# Remove rows having swapped column values

Tags: sql, view, common-table-expression

I have a table like

```
+ ----------------------- +
| RowID | FromCol | toCol |
+ ----------------------- +
| 1     | a       | b     |
| 2     | b       | c     |
| 3     | c       | d     |
| 4     | c       | b     |
| 5     | b       | a     |
+ ----------------------- +
```

I would like to remove the rows that has FromCol --> ToCol same value as ToCol --> FromCol
For eg. RowID 1 is a-->b and RowID 5 has b-->a so rowID 5 should be removed. Similarly RowID 4 should be removed because it has a swapped value like RowID 2.

My expected result Table is:

```
+ ----------------------- +
| RowID | FromCol | toCol |
+ ----------------------- +
| 1     | a       | b     |
| 2     | b       | c     |
| 3     | c       | d     |
+ ----------------------- +
```

I want to get this as a View preferably with CTE NOT using SQL CURSOR.
Can anybody help me please.
Thanks

Comment: **What have you tried?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar to @Barmar, but using a subquery instead of an inline table.

This works in SQL Server

```
select t1.*
FROM dbo.MyTest t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(t2.rowid) 
         FROM dbo.MyTest t2 
        WHERE t2.toCol= t1.fromCol
          AND t2.fromCol= t1.toCol
          AND t1.rowid> t2.rowid) = 0
```

Comment: I think the question was to remove the records not to select the records.

Comment: Actually, he wanted a query that would provide him with a view, rather than delete the records.

Comment: Thanks everybody, all solutions provide same results, for DELETE statement I can use NOT EXISTS to get my results.

Comment: @Mike Parkhill... one think I am not clear why you use = 0 ? what is its implication? Thanks

Comment: I'm comparing the result of the COUNT() to 0. It's restricting the result set to only records that don't have a swap row earlier in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it in MySQL, I'm not sure if the same syntax works in other SQL dialects.

```
DELETE t1
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2
WHERE t1.fromCol = t2.toCol
AND t1.toCol = t1.fromCol
AND t1.rowID > t2.rowID
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleas try

```
Delete from table where rowid in (select  f.id from table f INNER JOIN table fo on fo.tocol = f.fromcol and f.tocol = fo.fromcol and f.id > fo.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a pretty simple SQL like below:

```
SELECT RowID, FromCol, toCol
from my_table 
where FromCol > toCol
```

If your columns have strings, then you can use a simple hashing function to get integer numbers against them and then apply the comparison to them.